# Subclassing UIButton and make it IBDesignable

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subclass, ibdesignable

I have an app that uses custom buttons, the buttons should simply have a background image. Instead of adding the background image to all buttons, I'd rather have a UIButton subclass. It would be great if the custom button also rendered properly in Interface Builder. This is my attempt so far:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class STACPatientButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        NSLog("initWithFrame");
        super.init(frame: frame)
        _setup()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        NSLog("initWithCoder");
        super.init(coder: coder)
        _setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        _setup()
    }

    private func _setup() {
        if let image = UIImage(named:"patientButton.png") {
            let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0)
            let strechableImage = image.resizableImageWithCapInsets(insets)
            self.setBackgroundImage(strechableImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0)
            self.sizeToFit()
        }
    }

}
```

Where this is patientButton.png

[image]

Two problems:

1. the button doesn't render properly in Interface Builder. It just shows as a System button
2. the title doesn't display unless I resize the button in Interface Builder to allow space for the image; i.e., the `contentEdgeInsets` property and `sizeToFit` seem to have no effect

I guess it's a pretty basic question, but I can't any solution. Any advise?

EDIT 1 as per discussion with Matt below:

What I'm trying to achieve is to get some space around the title of the button. That was my understanding of `contentEdgeInsets` but it looks like I'm wrong. Without `contentEdgeInsets` this is the rendering of the button

[image]

which looks horrible. I want to programmatically get something like this, without having to resize the button in IB

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood what `contentEdgeInsets` does. For the inset of your background image, you need to implement this method:

```
override func backgroundRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return bounds.rectByInsetting(dx: 16, dy: 16)
}
```

For IBDesignable, what you're doing is structurally correct; if you delete your `_setup()` code and replace it with

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

the button will in fact be red in IB. So maybe IB just doesn't "do" background images set in code and so on.

Comment: I tried adding a simple intrinsicContentSize function returning a constant size; the function gets called but the button is not resized. I'll try with sizeToFit instead.

Comment: Well, it's not going to be resized in IB. I was suggesting what to do about it when the app runs...

Comment: Well, probably because you're not using auto layout. Implementing `intrinsicContentSize` certainly does work for me.

Comment: I'm using auto layout, or at least I think so. Can you post your complete code?

Comment: Implementing `sizeToFit` doesn't work either. It looks like the size of the button is fixed to whatever is set in IB. It must be something really stupid I'm missing here.

Comment: I've got another question - you're not expecting the `contentEdgeInsets` to affect the _background_ image, are you? Because it doesn't; it affects the title and internal image only.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you're trying to achieve. Could you draw a picture of how you're trying to get this button to look? I've deleted the part of my answer about the edge insets, since I don't know whether that's even relevant.

Comment: Ah, yes! I was expecting `contentEdgeInsets` to affect the background image. I guess that's why `intrinsicContentSize` doesn't do what I expect either. BTW, overriding `sizeToFit` works, but I have to disable auto layout.

Comment: Okay but `intrinsicContentSize` works too, if the button is under auto layout. You can return a constant size, or you can call super and adjust from there. That is how I would do it.

Comment: To achieve insetting of the background image, obviously you would need to implement `backgroundRectForBounds`. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It still looks like I'm not conveying clearly what I want to achieve. I've edited the original post with more details. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Ok, it looks like that `backgroundRectForBounds` with negative insets does the trick! Thanks again!